# How to upload a screenshot/image using Wicket

Tags: html, forms, image, upload, wicket

I want user to be able to easily upload screenshots into my application. (preferably without to many js/ajax trickery)

Is there a standard way in Wicket to allow an image to be pasted in some  `FormComponent` (`textarea`? `div` with `contenteditable`?) and used as a regular input, so that when the form is posted, I get a `byte[]`/stream in the Java code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `<input type="file">` in the markup and `FileUpload` component at the Java/server code.

If you need fancier ways than `Upload` button than you will need to use some Javascript library.

Here is the plain Wicket [example](http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/upload)

If you use Bootstrap then you may use Wicket-Bootstrap integrations like [FileInput](https://wb8.teliclab.info/extensions/BootstrapFileInput) or [DropZone](https://wb8.teliclab.info/extensions;#dropzonefileupload)

Comment: https://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/upload is down, but are you saying I paste image content directly in the `<input type='file'>` ? I think you only get a `browse` button?

Comment: @RobAu try with regular http instead of https. It should work.

Comment: @martin-g Ah yes, my browser seems to automagically try to upgrade to `https`. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be no example on these example that allow a screenshot to be copied from the clipboard.. I ended up writing my own (still fugly) by using a `contenteditable` div, an old-school `addEventListener` that listens for the paste, and a `AbstractBehaviour` for ajax-posting the data back to Wicket. If I find some extra time I might try to wrap it up in a proper component and share it somewhere..

Comment: You can also just provide another answer here with few snippets of your code and mark it as a solution :-)